Поставить курсор в файле на конец слова
void main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    ofstream out;
    out.open("MiFile.rtf");

    if (!out.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Файл не удалось открыть" << endl;
        return;
    }
    
    
    
    for (int i = 0; i <10; i++)
    {
        cout << out.tellp()<<endl;
        out << i+1<< " FSA\n";

    }
    out.close();
    out.open("MiFile.rtf",ios::app);
    
     //переместил курсор на 1 байт
    
    for ( int g = 10;  g < 20; g++)
    {
        int das= out.tellp();
        out.seekp( std::ios::beg);
        out <<"\t\t"<< g + 1 << " FSA\n";
        
    }
    
    out.close();

    ifstream in;
    in.open("MiFile.rtf");
    if (!in.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Файл не удалось открыть" << endl;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Файл открыт!" << endl;
        string str;
        while (!in.eof())
        {
            str = "";
            getline(in,str);
            cout << str<<endl;
        }
    }
}

Нужно чтобы перед 1 словом выводилось 11-е и так далее, не могу понять что делаю не так почему оно не хочет выводится в два столбика и как это сделать, пытался указатель ставить в разные позиции не дало особых результатов, предполагаю тут нужно к нулю прибавлять количество байт слова перед ним, но не знаю как сделать в seekp() чтобы оно всегда ставило указатель в конец слова строки и я дозаписывал строку

При записи после установки позиции контент перезаписывается с этого места, а не вставляется.

То есть единственный вариант это уже записывать строку вида 1 строка 51 строка, а не пытаться дописать или перезаписать? Судя по всему дописать что либо при изменении с курсором вообще не возможно?

Да, файл это так сказать сплошной блок памяти, который записывается последовательно, и не имеет у себя ничего подобного как добавление, такое реализуется исключительно вручную
